# Create TextView, animate it, and then remove. What is the best approach?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-animation

I'm learning android, and I have a test game where i am drawing onto a custom View. (e.g. with canvas ondraw).

At a certain points in the game, I want text numbers to pop up and then fade out. This is a common feature in games, for "critical hits" and the like. For example, this image:

[image: Critical hit]

What is the best approach for this, do I need to create TextViews programmatically and overlay them somehow?

Or should I be doing canvas.drawText( ? , somehow keeping track of how many bits of text I need to draw? If I took this approach, how would I best keep track of all the necessary texts.

I would then use a valueanimator to fade each one out.

I would love to hear some advice from an experience programmer on how this should best be tackled.

*Note - since there is a chance that the text may overlap views, I assume that creating textviews in code is the better option. Perhaps if I instantiate say 5 or 6 of them I can rotate the use of them to avoid garbage collection? I have no idea*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did it like this:

Created an array of a few TextViews, as a member variable. I was able to do this by first changing my Activity layout to a RelativeLayout. And then I put this code in the constructor to instantiate them:

```
popup_scores_ = new TextView[num_popups];
RelativeLayout test = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_layout);
for (int i = 0; i < num_popups; ++i) {
            popup_scores_ [i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            LayoutParams textViewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            test.addView(popup_scores_[i], textViewLayoutParams);
            popup_scores_[i].setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

And then at every time a display of the "fading popup score" was required. I would set one of the textviews to visible, and animate it's alpha property with an ObjectAnimator (from 1.0f to 0.0f).

I would rotate through the textviews so that even if there were multiple scores in succession, the popups would still be there fading out. Up to the limit of "num_popups".

Comment if you need elaboration on this method, or if you think I could have done it an easier way. Still learning here.